# Mongodb c# driver - copy Id to another field on insert

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I'm using .Net - mongodb c# driver for monngodb. When inserting the document I want to copy generated `[BsonId] ObjectId Id` field to another field in the document (duplicating the value)

I can run Insert, which will produce the key and then run update to copy the key to another field but this will leave the db in the "soft" state for a (brief) period of time.

Is it possible to do this "atomically" or am I using mongodb wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do that if you want the update to be atomic.

What I suggest you do is instead of having the driver set the Id, just create and set it yourself with `ObjectId.GenerateNewId` and then copy it before inserting the document into MongoDB:

```
entity.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
entity.IdCopy = entity.Id;
```

Comment: Are there any cons to generating application-side keys?

Comment: @Cortlendt well, technically it's always application-side as if you don't set the Id the driver does and not the server. So the only real difference is convenience.

Comment: @Cortlendt sure...  Any time.